# WebGL position different on desktop and android phone

Tags: android, webgl

I'm currently trying to create a website that contains a WebGL canvas. Everything worked fine and I got my plane rendered, but when I opened my website on my samsung galaxy SIII mini, the planes origin point seems to be different

You can check the website at http://portfolio.kamidesigns.be
The canvas is located under thesis -> Occluder simplification using planar sections

Here are some images to show what's wrong.

Desktop
[image]

Cellphone
[image]

The plane on my cellphone is located on the top right corner although the positions of the vertices of the plane are

```
var positions = new Float32Array([-0.5,  0.5, 0, 
                                  -0.5, -0.5, 0, 
                                   0.5,  0.5, 0, 
                                   0.5, -0.5, 0]);
```

If someone can help me, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of typos in your code which prevent vertex array object from being created properly. This leads to "default values" being fed through the vertex pipeline resulting in different behavior on different browsers.

Firstly, change your VAO initialization to this ( you missed `var vao` initialization):

```
function createVAO()
{
    var vao = gl.extOESVertexArrayObject.createVertexArrayOES();
    gl.extOESVertexArrayObject.bindVertexArrayOES(vao);
    return vao;
}
```

Secondly, in your `storeDataInAttributeList` calls you need to supply the result of `gl.getAttribLocation` for `attributeNumber`. This is a good thing to do to make your code stay correct if you modify the shader.

```
storeDataInAttributeList(program.aPosition, 3, positions);
storeDataInAttributeList(program.aTextureCoords, 2, textureCoords);
storeDataInAttributeList(program.aNormals, 3, normals);
```

And lastly, in your shader the `inNormal` attrib is not used which results in `gl.getAttribLocation(program, "inNormal");` returning -1

You may want to safe-guard your `storeDataInAttributeList` against such cases like this:

```
function storeDataInAttributeList(attributeNumber, coordinateSize, data)
{    
   if( attributeNumber >= 0 )
   {
       vbo = gl.createBuffer();
       gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);                 
       gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
       gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributeNumber);
       gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributeNumber, coordinateSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
       gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
   }
}
```

After making these 3 changes your page started displaying the same results on android/pc browser.

My final advice would be to avoid using OES_vertex_array_object extensions as e.g. my stock browser on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 doesn't support it ( not that old a device ).